# Non-proper intersection of surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, intersection-theory

I'm interested in the first basic case of excess intersection in intersection theory:

Let $X$ be a smooth projective 4-fold and let $S,T$ be two surfaces in $X$. Assume that the intersection $S\cap T$ contains an effective 1-cycle $D$ as its 1-dimensional part. In other words, $Z$ defines a Cartier divisor on $S$.

Is there some way of extracting information about $D$ as a divisor on $S$ (e.g., the self-intersection $D^2$) given the intersection number $S\cdot T$ and the normal bundles $N_S,N_T$?

Comment: In what sense are the normal bundles given? On $S$ and $T$, or on $Z$, or what? Does the intersection **contain** $Z$ or it **is** $Z$? Do you assume some kind of regularity (whatever this may mean in this situation)?

Comment: The normal bundle is a vector bundle on $S$, and say, I know the Chern classes. The 1-dimensional part of the intersection is $Z$. Feel free to assume that everything is smooth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is NO. Take $X=\mathbb{P}^4$, $S,T$ two smooth quadrics. Then $(S\cdot T)=4$, the normal bundles are $N_S=\mathcal{O}_S(1)\oplus \mathcal{O}_S(2)$, and same for $T$. If $S$ and $T$ are general, $Z=0$. If they are given by 
$$S:\ X=0\ ,\ YU+TV=0\quad;\quad T:\ Y=0\ ,\ XV+TU=0$$(coordinates $(X,Y,T,U,V)$ on $\mathbb{P}^4$), then $Z$ is the line $X=Y=T=0$ on $S$, with $Z^2=0$. If $S$ and $T$ lie in the same hyperplane, then $Z$ is a degree 4 elliptic curve in $S$, linearly equivalent to 2 times the hyperplane class $H$, and $Z^2=4H^2=8$.

Comment: Cheers! So there is in general not much hope to say anything about the divisor $Z$, e.g., when it is nef?

Comment: No. You could play the same game with two *cubic* surfaces (contained in a hyperplane), so that your 1-cycle may be a line (of square $-1$, hence not nef) or a triple of the hyperplane section.

Comment: So does @abx collect that bounty??

Comment: @B.Wellington — If you think these examples are good; please consider accepting this answer, by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer (below the votes).

Comment: Thanks, I'll wait a bit, in case there are other answers too.